# Joomla 2.5 session timer - when session is extending?

Tags: javascript, session, joomla, timer, counter

Im try to write Joomla session countdown for front-end users.
but I have problem to recognize when session is extending.

My code for now

```
<body data-sesja="<?php echo JFactory::getSession()->getExpire() ; ?>">
```

And JS

```
//getting session time
var licznik = $('body').data('sesja');

//PROBLEM IS HERE - becouse not all events extenting the session time
$('body').on('mousedown keyup', function(){
     licznik = $('body').data('sesja');
});

//creating counter object
var licznikObj = window.setInterval(function() {
    licznik--;
    $('.licznik').text(licznik);
    if (licznik == 0) {
         window.clearInterval(licznikObj);
         $('.licznik-info, .licznik').each(function(){
             $(this).remove();
         });
         $(".licznik-msg").text("Twoja sesja wygasła! Zaloguj ponownie.");
    }
 }, 1000);
```

So my question is: witch events extend Joomla 2.5 session time?

Comment: Perhaps I am getting this wrong, but what makes you think that client-side events have any effect on the Joomla session expiration? The session is renewed/extended by HTTP request (including XHR via AJAX).

Comment: Yes thanks, it's exacly what I want to know. But now is another question, is any option to globaly check when thats requests having place? Now I know that the The MosetsTree component have two Ajax/JSON requests in add "new listing" and another one is in module witch I made, but for example when I go to "edit my profile" sessions are never expires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am not exactly what you are trying to do, but I will describe in short the way sessions work in Joomla.

A default session is created on the first encounter a user has with the website.

When a user logs in, the session is coupled with its user record, so that the framework will automatically authenticate here in the following requests. Those session cookies are usually sent to the client w/o an expiration time, and therefore are valid (in the client side) until the browser session ends.

If the user ticks the 'remember me' box, an explicit expiration is set based on your configs, normally a few days into the future.

On the server side, on the other hand, the expiration time is stored regardless of what is stored on the client side. The default session length is 15 minutes (900 seconds).

If a user makes another request during this period, the session is extended by another time period (from the current request's time).

There is a behavior declaration (`JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');`) that generates a script that prevents the session from expiring by repeatedly sending AJAX requests to the server, usually 1 minute before it is set to expire.

This behavior is used quite often in the front-end.

I hope that this will help you get the results you are after. I cannot look into the behavior of a specific view of a commercial extension that I do not own.